# std::fstream file not getting created while making a custom Csv file manager class

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner to C++. I made a simple program which collects information of cars and stores it into classes. This was just for the purpose of learning more about classes. I wanted to store the data of cars to a csv file. But it is very complicated so I tried to make a class called CSVFile to manage csv files. But I cant even get the constructors to work. I don't get any error, but when i make an object it doesn't create the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class CSVFile {
public:
    CSVFile(std::string _name): name(_name) {
        file.open(name);

    }
private:
    std::ifstream file;
    std::string name;
};

int main() {
    CSVFile myFile("my.csv");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't create the file? Maybe it just creates it in a different directory to what you expect?

Comment: I'd suggest to start reading documentation/tutorials, these are all basics: `ifstream` is for reading from files so won't create a new file. You don't get any errors because you don't check for hem: use `is_open`. (or make `open` throw by `file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit)`) Might be wiser to split in CsvReader and CsvWriter, one using an `ifstream` the other `ofstream`

Comment: Have a look at [std::basic_ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) and look at the `is_open` member to validate whether the file open succeeded. Then save [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) to use as your online C++ reference (best on the net) It (like anything else) takes a bit of time to learn where all the pieces are stored and hidden, but well worth the effort.

Comment: Hi @ihsan, keep in mind that opening a file in a constructor is a bad practice because constructors are only intended to initialize objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file opened successfully when I opened it with std::fstream::app append mode.